# Can I attach a Zip Drive to a Hard Disk Enclosure?

Tags: external-hard-drive, pata, enclosures, zip-drive

I have a [3.5 inch IDE/SATA (it has cables for both) enclosure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002MUGUFK), an old [internal IDE Zip drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007VEFPI) and 20 Zip disks. I just want to pull whatever's on them off and store the files somewhere else.  I'm not looking for any kind of finished, permanent solution.

I'm pretty ignorant on the hardware side of things, but I thought it might work to just frankenstein these together and purge these old disks from my life. So, good idea?  If not, what else can I do?

(I don't have any desktops lying around, otherwise I'd just throw it in one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the connectors involved nothing will be damaged if you plug the zip drive into the ide connector.  Give it a go and find out, the worst that I can see happening is that it just won't work.

Comment: OK, good.  I didn't want to ignorantly fry anything.  I'll report back.  Hold my beer!

Comment: You may have to do some hunting around for drivers that work with your current OS.

Comment: I installed a driver that made my PC not boot.  Refreshing it now. :(

Comment: when you just plugged it in and before any special drivers were installed what happened?

Comment: Windows made the USB discovery sound but no drives showed up in Windows Explorer.  I tried the driver assuming it was required.

Comment: The disk may not of had valid partition and format information. Try looking in the "computer manager" / "computer management" under the disk manager section. You may need to format the disk before it will show up in windows explorer.

Comment: @Dzejms Did you ever get this to work? I'm in a similar situation now with some old media / drives.

Comment: I gave up on it. :(

Answer (score 2):

This ought to work just fine.

The IDE Zip-drive will appear to the OS as a removable hard-disk.
Any modern OS should be able to handle it out of the box.

I would recommend to connect it by IDE though.
Simply because that is the natural way to do it for this drive. The least conversion (to SATA) the better.

If your motherboard still has a IDE connecter connect it directly to that. That would be even better.

Don't forget the jumper the Zip drive as Master. IDE requires those jumpers to be set properly.

P.S.
Don't be surprised if it is damn slow. Zip drives are a fair bit slower than hard-drives.

Comment: I didn't change the jumper, that's probably really important.

Comment: The OP only mentioned sata because the external drive enclosure has connectors for both.  He isn't using the sata connector, because his zip drive only has ide.

Comment: @Dzejms yes, lots of IDE devices require correct placement of their jumpers.

Comment: @BeowulfNode42 Considering SATA vs IDE: I have seen several enclosures that internally and externally had both style connectors and one of them would be indirect, connected to the other by a SATA-IDE conversion chip. (Logically that are 2 separate conversions: On for the enclosure to present itself as IDE or SATA device to the host. The other to internally act has host for both type of drives.) If memory serves Silicon Image makes a chip that handles all of that in a single package.

Comment: I tried the master setting, cable select, and slave. Only slave (no pin connector, it didn't have a pin connector) made the drive connection sound (tho no drive actually appeared in My Computer). The drive spits out the zip disk as soon as I put it in.

Comment: @BT If it shucks the disk right out the drive-mechnism is jammed or broken. It may unfreeze after trying it 15-20 times. As for not showing in Windows. It may be needed there has to be a disk in the drive when Windows boots for it to recognize it. If that is the case it is also NOT removable when Windows is running. This has to do with the fact that IDE drives were never designed to be removable and many enclosures threat it as non-removable. Last: It is also possible that your enclosure just isn't compatible with ZIP drives.